# Need to understand Microsoft Teams integration to build some AI features

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to understand how companies like [fireflies.ai](https://fireflies.ai/integrations/microsoftteams) integrated MicrosoftTeams to get AI features like automatic transcription, notes etc. It seems there is no API to get a recording of Audio data. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way, by creating a [policy recording bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-recording-policy) to be able to record the audio.  Once you have a audio stream it's easy enough to translate the audio stream using something like [azure cognitive services speech to text](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech-to-text/) apis.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. Once the recording is done by bot, can one get access to recorded file for transcription or is it needed to use only microsoft/azure apis to get transcription ?

Comment: It's up to you.  The bot will get a raw PCM audio stream.  You can do what you like with it.  Save it to a file (wav format) / encode it and save it to a file (e.g. mp3), stream it to a translating service live and get the continious translation results back and do whatever you like with the results.  You could save it to a file, then stream it as a whole recording to a translation service and get whatever the result back and do what you want with it.  It's all up to you.

Comment: Super. Let me explore that and comeback. Thanks again